# Delete string from a file with beginning and ending tag like <ex></ex> in a shell script

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a bash script to uncomment a comment with beginning of a tag
ex;

```
/*<O33>*/
    //  here my code
/*</O33>*/
```

Here's my script, and I successfully uncomment it.

```
sed -i "/^[ \t]*\/\*<O33>\*\//,/^[ \t]*\/\*<\/O33>\*\//s/\/\///g" $Path/DebugVersion.c
```

and this is the result:

```
/*<O33>*/
      here my code
/*</O33>*/
```

Now I'm trying the reverse the process, to recomment the string between the begin and end tags, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: show how should look the new result

Comment: If the code is C or C++, you should use `#ifdef DEBUG_WANTED` and `#endif` to mark the beginning and the end (for any suitable choice of macro name).  Then you don't have to edit the code to add or remove the debug code; you simply recompile with or without `-DDEBUG_WANTED` or equivalent on the command line.

Comment: May I observe that the choice of capital letter O followed by digits 33 is easily misinterpreted — it is not a good choice of tag name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task of reinserting the comments is a little trickier because you do not want to insert the `//` markers on the start and end lines.  I ended up with a file, `script.sed`, that contained:

```
\@/\*<O33>\*/@, \@/\*</O33>\*/@ {
    \@/\*</\{0,1\}O33>\*/@ ! s%\([[:space:]]*\)%&//%
}
```

I then ran:

```
$ sed -f script.sed data
 /*<O33>*/
        //here my code
    /*</O33>*/
$
```

Your pattern matching is complicated by the presence of `/` and `*` in the material to be matched.  One way around this is to change `sed`'s search character by using, in this case, `\@` to tell it that `@` marks the end of the pattern.  (You can choose any other character that's convenient: `=` or `%` work well too.) The first line has the form *`patt1, patt2`*`{` where the first pattern looks for `/*<O33*/` (note that is a capital letter O, not a zero) and the second looks for `/*</O33>*/`.  The `{` starts grouping the commands.  It means that lines in the range from the first pattern to the second pattern will be subjected to the commands contained within the matching braces `{` … `}`.

The second line uses a slightly different variant on the pattern match to identify both begin and end lines (the `/\{0,1\}` is the classic `sed` way of finding 0 or 1 instances of `/`; if you use modern extended regexes, it is equivalent to `/?`).  The `!` operator inverts the sense of the match; only lines that do not match the end tags will be subjected to the `s%%%` substitution.  This avoids inserting `//` in front of `/*<O33>*/`, for example.

The `s%\([[:space:]]*\)%&//%` operation looks for zero or more leading white space characters (blanks or tabs), and adds `//` after them.  Again, this avoids using `s///` because `/` is part of the replacement text.

This can all be squished into one line rather than needing a separate script file, but I like script files because I don't have to fight the shell.  That's not a big problem here; there are no quotes — single, double or back — to confuse things.  Use single quotes around the script unless you need to interpolate shell variables into the script.  If you must use double quotes, you have to double up the backslashes, and it rapidly gets fiddly.  Avoid double quotes around the script if you can.

```
$ sed '\@/\*<O33>\*/@, \@/\*</O33>\*/@ { \@/\*</\{0,1\}O33>\*/@ ! s%\([[:space:]]*\)%&//%; }' data
 /*<O33>*/
        //here my code
    /*</O33>*/
$
```

The trailing semicolon is optional in GNU `sed`; it is necessary in BSD (macOS) and classic `sed`.

I note in passing that in the decommenting `sed` script, you have:

```
s/\/\///g
```

The `g` is probably not a good idea.  If you have:

```
/*<O33>*/
//    printf("%s\n", __func__);  // Identify the function!
/*</O33*/
```

Then the uncommenting operation will leave:

```
/*<O33>*/
    printf("%s\n", __func__);   Identify the function!
/*</O33*/
```

removing the second comment marker too.  The code won't compile.  Drop the `g`; you only want to remove the first comment marker on the lines.  (Clearly, if you only use `//` comments to disable blocks of code, this isn't critical — but it is safer in the long run.)

Also note that if you're working in C or C++ with the C preprocessor available, you'd do better to use:

```
#ifdef O33
    printf("%s\n", __func__);   // Identify the function!
#endif
```

as you don't have to edit the file to enable or disable the code; you can simply recompile with or without `-DO33` or equivalent.

Comment: i dont get my answer bcos i dont understand, but i learn and will learn much from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i learn from Jonathan's answer and SLePort's answer and i get it.

```
sed -i "/^[ \t]*\/\*<O33>\*\//,/^[ \t]*\/\*<\/O33>\*\//d" $Path/DebugVersion.c
```